# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'giphy_client' (Discord bot & Heroku)

Tags: python, heroku, discord, bots

Trying to get my Discord bot up and running via Heroku.
Deploying worked, but the bot is offline in Discord.

The logs are telling me something is happening within the code of the bot (which I named Giphy.py).

Log:

```
Starting process with command `python giphy.py`
2022-01-13T11:23:28.488578+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-01-13T11:23:28.964012+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-01-13T11:23:28.964026+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/giphy.py", line 3, in <module>
2022-01-13T11:23:28.964082+00:00 app[worker.1]: import giphy_client
2022-01-13T11:23:28.964083+00:00 app[worker.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'giphy_client'
```

Code:

```
import random
import discord
import giphy_client
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from giphy_client.rest import ApiException
...
...
```

I can see it causing a ModuleNotFoundError, but, since I have made the bot work locally, and given the fact that I am still quite new to the world of Python and bots, I have no idea what to do now. Is there a way to import the giphy_client? Or should I do something different to solve the issue and have my bot up and running online? Appreciate all feedback. Again, am quite new still!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! Here is the **answer**:

The "requirements.txt" file, which contains stuff like:

- PyNaCl==1.3.0
- dnspython==1.16.0
- etc.

was missing the one thing I also needed: *giphy_client==1.0.0*.

After adding this, the bot was online and usable in the server.